# Переопределить стандартные функции или

Tags: php

В общем есть задачка, опишу в общих чертах - можно ли в глобальном неймспейсе объявить свой класс и в нём словить выполнение стандартных функций? К примеру:

```
class A {
    public function __construct()
    {
        <some trigger> { class_alias(self::class, 'B'); }
    }
}
$a = new A();

if(class_exists('B'))
    echo 'exists!';
```

Вот, что я должен сделать, чтоб отловить вызов `class_exists` и запустить триггер, возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: как мне это должно помочь?) мне нужно без дополнительных телодвижений либо отловить вызов class_exists либо переопределить его на свой. но переопределить его не могу, т.к. namespace только глобальный, а по другому не знаю как

Comment: Вам вероятно это не нужно. class_exists умеет триггерить autoload

Comment: вот оно! благодарю)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не стоит удалять свои вопросы после того, как вы получили на них ответ. Мы строим базу знаний, возможно, что ваш вопрос и ответ помогут кому-то найти ответ на сайте, не ожидая решения. (В такой же ситуации наверняка можете оказаться и вы, найдя чей-то вопрос, похожий на ваш).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class_exists по умолчанию активирует механизм автозагрузки.
Просто зарегистрируйте нужный вам автозагрузчик.

```
class A {
    public static function init() {
        spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
           class_alias(self::class, $class);
        });
    }
}

A::init();

echo class_exists('B') ? 'Exists' : 'Not exists'; // Exists
```